# Function find() does not recognize letter

Tags: python

find() don't work in my code.

I don't know why find() does not recognize letter.
following is my code.

```
def search(Object, maze_row, letter) :
        Object[0] += 1
        Object[1] = maze_row.find(letter)

def main() :
    row_col = "5 5"
    input_maze = "#####\n#..B#\n#.#.#\n#RO.#\n#####"

    maze = input_maze.split('\n')
    red_ball = [-1,-1]
    blue_ball = [-1,-1]
    hole = [-1,-1]

    for maze_row in maze :
        search(red_ball, maze_row,'R')
        search(blue_ball, maze_row,'B')
        search(hole, maze_row,'O')
        if(red_ball[1] >= 0 and blue_ball[1] >= 0 and hole[1] >= 0) :
            break

    print(red_ball, blue_ball, hole)


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

***result is ([4, -1], [4, -1], [4, -1])***

Answer (score 0):

`find()` is finding your letter.

However, in subsequent loops of `for maze_row in maze` it is setting back `Object[1]` to `-1` due to the fact that the element can't be found in the next maze_row.

You can solve this in a variety of ways, with the most concise being to change your search function:

```
def search(Object, maze_row, letter) :
    Object[0] += 1
    if Object[1] == -1:
        Object[1] = maze_row.find(letter)
```

Edit: Indentation

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with `find`.

The problem is that your code keeps looping over the rows even after you find a match and set the correct index.

The only condition that would break from the loop is when the three letters `R`, `B`, `O` all occurs in the same row, which obviously is impossible.

So when you try to print the three variables, you would see the result for the last row, which contains none of your target letters.

It would be simpler if you create a function to search for the row and column of a letter in a maze:

```
def search(maze, target):
    for i, row in maze:
        j = row.find(target)
        if j != -1:
            return i, j
    return -1, -1

red_ball = search(maze, 'R')
```